# PhoneGap external site displaying in browser for Android

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I am having a issue with phonegap/cordova. I am trying to get the app to display content on a external site. I basically need just a wrapper app, but also need a means to access phone resources like, the camera etc. I am placing my external site in the content tag in my config.xml but phonegap is just opening the site in a external browser rather then in the phonegap app. This works fine in iOS and before I start ripping apart this framework to make this work I was wondering if someone else has a workaround to solve this problem. I have build a app like this before in android so I know it works but it was with a older version of phonegap. The version I am using is Phonegap 3.6.3

Here is my config.xml file;

```
<widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    id        = "io.cordova.helloCordova"
    version   = "2.0.0">

<!-- Preferences for Android -->
<preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />
<content src="https://myExternalSite.com/" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<access origin="*" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered the issue was I pointed the  to a sub domain which redirected me to login so rather then just opening in the phone-gap container it opened in a external browser.

The fix was as simple as:

to

I guess if anyone has the same issue verify your site isn't redirecting you as soon as you hit the site.

Comment: Can you mark the thread [SOLVED] for people coming later. TIA

Answer (score 0):

From the [official Docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#window.open)

```
var ref = window.open(url, target, options);
```

- ref: Reference to the InAppBrowser window. (InAppBrowser)
- url: The
  URL to load (String). Call encodeURI() on this if the URL contains
  Unicode characters.
- target: The target in which to load the URL, an
  optional parameter that defaults to _self. (String)

  - _self: Opens in the Cordova WebView if the URL is in the white list, otherwise it opens in the InAppBrowser.
  - _blank: Opens in the InAppBrowser.
  - _system: Opens in the system's web browser.
- options: Options for the InAppBrowser. Optional, defaulting to: location=yes. (String)

---

One issue with this is that it open another window that is a webbrowser. At that point the hardware on the mobile device is no longer available.
As to what to do next, I could speculate alot. However, it would be easier if you explained what are you trying to do?